# Django Robots.txt Change Content-Type Header

Tags: python, django, content-type, robots.txt

Firefox error:
​
The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.

Using https://django-robots.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
​

It should probably be:

content="text/html; charset=utf-8" or "text/plain; charset=UTF8" not 'text/plain'
​

Current code:

```
url(r'^robots\.txt/', include('robots.urls')),
```

​
​
Alternatives? 
​

```
path('robots.txt', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="robots.txt", content_type='text/plain')),
url(r'^robots.txt', lambda x: HttpResponse("User-Agent: *\nDisallow:", content_type="text/plain"), name="robots_file"),
```

​
​
How do you combine include('robots.urls') with the alternatives or is it not possible? 
​
​

```
curl -s -D - 127.0.0.1:8000/robots.txt/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 14 Apr 2020 01:05:52 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.3
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Comment: Which django version are you using?

Comment: @Geancarlo Murillo The newest one, 3.0.5